# Deleting column faster way

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
j = WS.Cells(1, WS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = j To 1 Step -1
    If WS.Cells(1, i).Value = "" Or WS.Cells(1, i).Value = "--" Then
       WS.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Currently, I'm doing a backward for-loop running from the last column to the first column, conditionally deleting the column. I would like to know if there is a smarter, faster way of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete columns faster, then delete them all at once instead of one at a time.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColumns()
    Dim columnsToDelete As Range
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    For i = lastColumn To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i)) = 0 Then
            If columnsToDelete Is Nothing Then Set columnsToDelete = Columns(i) Else Set columnsToDelete = Union(columnsToDelete, Columns(i))
        End If
    Next i
    columnsToDelete.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, loop with union and delete afterwards seems working faster

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative wording based on the article
[How to Delete Empty Columns through VBA in Microsoft Excel](https://www.exceltip.com/cells-ranges-rows-and-columns-in-vba/delete-empty-columns-through-vba.html),
but I don't know if it will be any faster.

```
j = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
  For i = j To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(j)) = 0 Then
      Columns(j).Delete
    End If
Next i
```